# Как избежать вызов метода в юнит-тесте DRF?

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

Не могу разобраться как правильно использовать `unittest.mock.patch`.
Мне нужно протестировать `APIView` с помощью `rest_framework.test.APITestCase.client`, но не вызывать определенный метод.

```
class MyClass(MyMixin):
    def do_some_stuff(self, request):
        self.should_be_called_in_the_test()
        self.should_not_be_called_in_the_test()

class MyView(views.APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        my_object = MyClass()
        my_object.do_some_stuff(request)
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

#test.py:
class MyViewTest(APITestCase):
    def test_post_request(self):
        url = reverse('my-view-url')
        # Как правильно подменить вызов 
        # should_not_be_called_in_the_test() на пустышку?
        response = self.client.post(url, data)
        # some asserts...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   with patch('app.views.MyClass.should_not_be_called_in_the_test'):
        response = self.client.post(url, data)
    # some asserts...
```